# Can't install apache2 after uninstall

Tags: software-installation, apache2

Long story short, I had to move a running bugzilla version from Windows into Ubuntu.  I had the a fresh installation of bugzilla running yesterday, but when I tried to bring the data in, the css and scripts where not displaying the site correctly.  I tried setting the owner and user of the files and directories, I found that apache was having rights issues. I tried getting help from bugzilla, but no one replied with the correct fix.  I thought that if I remove apache and install it back, it would fix the security problems.  Well, was I wrong...!

I have tried a good 4-5 times to,

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
whereis apache2
```

and then used

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2
```

on any directory that resulted from the `whereis` command. Now, I can not install apache2 on the system. Here is my last install try:

```
$ apt-get install --only-upgrade apache                        2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 105 not upgraded.

$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

returns nothing.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Well, is doing a lot of upgrade... give me a sec..  Also, it's a log of data, how can I paste here where I can only paste 500 characters or so?

Comment: Use https://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Here is the update, [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VH8HCSTFw5/)

Comment: sorry, reversed... here is the update [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rH6dT8QcHh/) the other one was the upgrade.  Apologies...

Comment: this is the latest upgrade [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/J8DWZrMghh/)

Comment: Don't run `sudo` on a root prompt. Did apache ever work? Show us what happens when you try-and-fail to uninstall apache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73507/discussion-between-jicman-and-user535733).

Comment: apparently, there is a bug with apache. Per user535733: "Looks like a problem or bug with apache. That I cannot help with, sorry. New question time."

Comment: But the *original* problem, Apache won't reinstall, seems solved. It reinstalled without an apt or dpkg error.

Comment: Ok, maybe I was obscure: the phrase "apache won't reinstall" is that it does goes through the motion, but after it finishes, there is no installation of apache2.  That's what I meant by it won't reinstall.  Because, even thought it went through the motion, the software is not working.  As a matter of fact, /usr/sbin/apache2 is not even there.

Comment: Were there any errors during the install? It's really doubtful that apache2 has a critical-failure bug that *only* you are suffering from.

Comment: Easy to check: Fire up a fresh Virtual Machine with the same release of Ubuntu. Install apache. If it works in the VM, then you know the problem is not apache nor apt.

Comment: This is the installation run after you helped me [link] https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/b4c6svBVXk/

Comment: Like I said, I had it working, but...  Yes, that would be the next thing to do if I can't get it to work.

Comment: I think you have shown pretty conclusively that you no longer have apt errors, and that the packages you wanted re-installed are now properly re-installed. That seems to have been your original question. If apache, properly installed, is not working as you expect or is throwing errors, then that's a *different* AskUbuntu question.

Comment: Ok, I can go for that.  I will open another one saying that after the installation, /usr/sbin/apache2 did not get install.  Thanks.

Comment: This is what I did to fix the problem:
> apt-get remove apache2*
then followed by
> apt-get install apache2

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to fix the problem:

> apt-get remove apache2*

then followed by

> apt-get install apache2

Comment: Can be done in one step: `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}\n' 'apache2*' | sed -ne 's/^i //p' | xargs sudo apt-get install --reinstall`

Comment: By the time I type that, those two commands above would have been completed. :-)

Comment: Fair enough....